# Server Resource Pack not working with link to Dropbox

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I uploaded my custom resource pack to my dropbox. But if I use a link to said resource pack in `server.properties`, it never works for some reason. It does work fine when I use a direct link (from a popular resource pack, not hosted on dropbox).

I want to know how I get the dropbox one to work. How can I get it to work?
and here is my link,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4towhzbjyf6238p/server-resorucepack.zip?dl=1

Comment: Is the zip structure correct? All the resource pack files need to be in the root of the zip and not a containing folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your able to do this by changing the `dl=0` to `dl=1` at the end of the DropBox URL. I've used this method several times to host server resource packs on DropBox.

What's happening is that when dl = 0 it will show the downloads page with the button for that file, and when you do dl = 1, it's a direct link to download the actual file.

Here is a guide by a the Minecraft server hosting company, MCProHosting on doing what you want with photos https://clients.mcprohosting.com/knowledgebase/96/How-to-Add-a-Resource-Pack-to-a-Minecraft-Server.html

Comment: Check the edits on OP, s/he had a dl=1 at the end.

Comment: @ardaozkal err, what? I don't see them saying that anywhere

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/251442/1

Comment: @ardaozkal oooh, I'm on the mobile SE app, and edits aren't obvious on it

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox can support it, but you need a little more than just dl=1.

The thing is that usual Dropbox links ("get dropbox link" thing) generate links to Dropbox page, not the file.

You can alter the link to aim it to file server directly, instead.

This is done by this change, here is original link:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/somestring...?dl=0
```

And here is the link you need. Be aware it leads to totally another server, which has no HTML content, so you access the files directly:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/somestring...?dl=1
```

As you can see, the alternating of the start of URL does the thing. 
For `dl=0` or `dl=1` , the thing is, that for some files it can do difference if it starts to download or it shows in browser. So pictures etc. with `dl=0` will just show in browser, but with `dl=1` they are forced to download.

You need the server to directly download the file and not comunicate it with HTML nor show the file, so you need to change the `dl=1`, too. (However it could probably work with `?dl=0` totally deleted or with keeping =0, too, because ZIP file is not the type to be shown in browser, so it downloads anyway).

NOTE: Do not change the string identifying the file and user in between.

Comment: The only way I have found to get the proper link is to have the DropBox client, right click on Windows/ctrl+click on Mac the file and click `Copy Public Link`.  If you copy the link from the website, it just gives you the incorrect link, and I have been unable to find a way to copy the correct link online.

Comment: Also sadly it is not possible (or just extremely difficult) to convert the `dropbox.com` link to the proper `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` link.

Comment: Well, yes, I use the desktop appliaction and use it for generating the links, but then it worked everytime for me. I host modpacks for technic launcher for my servers that way and never had problem when using mentioned method.